# Update to Django 1.5 ajax csrf middleware 403

Tags: ajax, django, django-1.5, django-1.4, django-csrf

I have a website where user clicks on the fav button and an ajax request will be sent. I have the following in the template.

```
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        contentType:'application/json',
        data: {
                query : query,
                id : {{ photo.id }},
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
        },
        dataType:'json',
```

and more...Everything works fine but after I upgraded to 1.5.5 the request says forbidden
in the inspect element of chrome. If I downgrade to 1.4 everything works fine though...Why
is this happening..Is there some settings I need to add like middleware or something . But on normal forms(like login) no csrf issues were found. When I checked the source of my pages, the csrf part is rightly filled, and can be seen in the request in chrome inspect element also.

Can someone suggest some solutions for this.
Thanking you in advance,
Thomas

Comment: Can you see the CSRF_TOKEN in your script - is it sending it with the ajax request?

Comment: @limelights Yes it is...When I check the header tab in chrome it is there Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:djdt=hide; sessionid=kptwl13umz2eyi1dv9tdbs2a0zxfrxnk; csrftoken=KoOiL2FIl3vlg7ergaVYDVIWdWYeWJbL
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/photos/view/1047/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
query=add_to_fav&id=1047&csrfmiddlewaretoken=KoOiL2FIl3vlg7ergaVYDVIWdWYeWJbL  As you can see the cookie value and data matches.

Comment: The only difference to csrf presented in 1.5 is [not enclosing the csrf_token template tag with a div](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#miscellaneous). Are you sure you didn't change anything else maybe?

Comment: is the error that the token is missing or that the token is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

If you use it this way:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", {{ csrf_token }});
    },
    ...
```

Does it work?

Comment: Yes it works, It removed the csrf verification problem but new problem is that the request.POST variable is empty..Although in the header the payload is there in chrome, the view is getting an empty request.POST...I always bumb into stupid issues like this...what do you think about this?

Comment: When I read the docs, in django 1.5 non form data is not included in request.POST and is available in request.body which I checked and works...but before I make code changes can you confirm this?

Comment: check the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2.5/#csrf-exception-for-ajax-requests but body is like raw data and you can't do .get() to get the keys it seems...

Comment: Problem has been solved by changed the contenttype of ajax to application/x-www-form-urlencoded from application/json. Also removing  the contenttype from ajax also worked. Thank you.